# SQL . Call midnight timestamp unix without having to enter it manually

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 4 columns value , animal_id, food_id and timestamp. Time stamp records the data in unix time. Currently my script is working fine and produces a table like this. This is all great and all but this forces me to go edit the file and change the timestamp each day for today's midnight timestamp and this is quite time consuming. Is there a way to produce this line of code for every day without having to update it ? Thank you in advance. I use oracle 10g.

The line in the script I want to change

WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1406073600 AND (1406073600 + 86400)

The Script

```
SELECT MAX(value),animal_id, food_id 
FROM farm1 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1406073600 AND (1406073600 + 86400)
group by animal_id, food_id ;
```

The Table Results

```
MAX(VALUE)  animal_id    food_id
---------- ---------- ----------
      9302          8       9081
      8015         10       9081
```

Comment: Why are you storing it as a Unix timestamp at all, rather than a native `DATE` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a date to a Unix-style epoch timestamp number with:

```
(your_date - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24
```

... since the timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.

So to run your query for all records yesterday (which your sample seems to be doing):

```
SELECT MAX(value),animal_id, food_id 
FROM farm1 
WHERE timestamp >= (trunc(sysdate - 1) - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24
AND timestamp < (trunc(sysdate) - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24
GROUP by animal_id, food_id ;
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive so will catch both midnights, which could potentially lead to a value being included in two days' runs, or skewing the results for one of them. I've changed from that to explicit `>=` and `<` to make it inclusive. Or you could just subtract 1 from the later time of course, to make it 23:59:59.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17e67/1) (including a value being picked up from the wrong with your original query).

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve it would be to convert each timestamp to a *conceptual* date and use the virtual column `systimestamp`:

```
SELECT MAX(value),animal_id, food_id 
FROM farm1 
WHERE TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'YYYYMMDD') = TO_CHAR(systimestamp, 'YYYYMMDD')
group by animal_id, food_id ;
```

Comment: to_char creates strings, not dates.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. This would still require me to input data such as 20140722 in which is not my goal. My goal is so I would not have to do this.

Comment: The field `timestamp` is populated automatically, isn't it?